# razorpay oauth payment says does not have sufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth, payment, razorpay

As i have integrated razorpay oauth application with my spring and react application.
and i am storing merchant's access_token,refresh_token,public_token in my DB.
now i have created an order from backend using API_keys and returned to front end
on front side when react-razorpay  window open and i proceed with transaction 
it gives me error like 'The OAuth token used does not have sufficient permissions for this
request'
please find below screen shot attached
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When authorization process is performed that in scope parameter we need to set  scope=read_Write then it is working